Android animatedVectorResource causes Resources$NotFoundException
I'm trying to use AnimatedImageVector.animatedVectorResource to display an animation in Compose, but every mentioned call causes an exception:
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0

The resource ID is always 0x0 even if I use different resource files. When debugging there is a real resource ID provided to this method but somewhere inside of the androidx it changes from the proper value to 0.
Here is interesting part of stacktrace:
at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:234)
at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1439)
at androidx.compose.ui.res.VectorResources_androidKt.vectorResource(VectorResources.android.kt:65)
at androidx.compose.animation.graphics.vector.compat.XmlAnimatedVectorParser_androidKt.parseAnimatedImageVector(XmlAnimatedVectorParser.android.kt:74)
at androidx.compose.animation.graphics.res.AnimatedVectorResources_androidKt.loadAnimatedVectorResource(AnimatedVectorResources.android.kt:61)
at androidx.compose.animation.graphics.res.AnimatedVectorResources_androidKt.animatedVectorResource(AnimatedVectorResources.android.kt:48)

At this line androidx.compose.animation.graphics.res.AnimatedVectorResources_androidKt.loadAnimatedVectorResource(AnimatedVectorResources.android.kt:61) resId is valid but in the next stacktrace step androidx.compose.animation.graphics.vector.compat.XmlAnimatedVectorParser_androidKt.parseAnimatedImageVector(XmlAnimatedVectorParser.android.kt:74) it is somehow reloaded from AttributeSet and gets 0.
Is it a bug in the androidx.compose.animation.graphics.vector library or do I need to set something special?
My code is very similar to the google example from this page https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/compose/animation/vectors I only use different drawable resource.
